# How can I add an filter attribute to every virtual properties in EF generated entity class?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to add a filter attribute to every virtual properties in Entity Framework auto generated entity class, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you're using DatabaseFirst, you should have a `Model.tt` file in your project that autogenerates the entity classes.
Inside of that `Model.tt` there's a `WriteProperty` function that actually generates the properties, you could add your attribute right there. It looks something like this:

```
void WriteProperty(string accessibility, string type, string name, string getterAccessibility, string setterAccessibility)
{
#>
    [YourCustomFilterAttribute]
    <#=accessibility#> <#=type#> <#=name#> { <#=getterAccessibility#>get; <#=setterAccessibility#>set; }
<#+
}
```

You could of course play with `type`, `name` and other parameters if you need to apply the attribute conditionally.